# Tableview menu not scrolling till the bottom swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a slight problem, my menu which I created doesn't seem to want to scroll till the bottom.

I have created it programmaitacally

```
var dataSource = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(CellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    
}

func addTransparentView(frames: CGRect) {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    transparentView.frame = window?.frame ?? self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(transparentView)
    
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height, width: frames.width, height: 50)
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
    tableView.reloadData()
    let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeTransparentView))
    transparentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)
    transparentView.alpha = 0
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 2.0, initialSpringVelocity: 2.0, options: .curveEaseInOut,animations: {
        self.transparentView.alpha = 0.5
        self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height + 1, width: frames.width, height: CGFloat(self.dataSource.count * 50))
    }, completion: nil)
    
    
}

@objc  func removeTransparentView() {
    let frames = selectedButton.frame
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut,animations: {
        self.transparentView.alpha = 0
        self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: frames.origin.x, y: frames.origin.y + frames.height, width: frames.width, height: 0)
    }, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func onClickSelectProperty(_ sender: Any) {
    dataSource = ["Apartment A3","Apartment A4","Apartment A5","Apartment A6","Apartment A8","Apartment A9","Apartment A12","Apartment E1","Sectional Title 50A","Sectional Title 65A","Free Standing 70A","Free Standing 70A Core","Free Standing 85A","Free Standing 100A"]
    selectedButton = btnSelectPropert
    addTransparentView(frames: btnSelectPropert.frame)
}
```

I would like to scroll till the bottom, somehow it doesn't allow me

[how the table/menu looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IXlB.png)

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting of your code and attach an image of how it's not scrolling to the bottom?

Comment: That's because the height of your table view is always fixed and adapts to the number of rows, so it's not scrollable because table view thinks that all content is visible. Align the bottom of the table view to the bottom of the safe area so that the height of the table view is less that the height of its content and it will be scrollable.

Comment: the tableview is added programmatically, I didn't't add it in the storyboard.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you add a table view programmatically or via a storyboard. You can still use Auto Layout without storyboards/XIBs. If you really don't want to use it and calculate the frames manually like in your example, you still need to set the frame of the table view so that it doesn't go beyond the safe area.